# How to insert List data from ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, spring-boot, jsp, arraylist

I have two Entity

That relations is 1:N.

A Entity has `List<Bentity> getList = new ArrayList<>();`

And i'll send Some data from jsp ajax data.

```
var data={
  a:1,
  b:2,
  getList[0].abcdKey:1
}

$.post(url,data,function(){ blah})
```

One size array has done But 2 or more size Array can't sending.

I try to

```
var getList=[]
    var data=[1,2,3,4]  // it is  "getList[0].abcdKey:1'"s data
        data.forEach(function(){ 
        getList.push({

           getList[i].abcdKey:1  //then occured error
        })
        })

var data={
      a:1,
      b:2,
      getList
    }

    $.post(url,data,function(){ blah})
```

What i change to my code?

Back-end Spring-boot
Front-end jsp + jquery+javascript

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Back-end  spring boot 
front-end jsp
 thanks

Comment: what does `getList` have in it ?  post that as well also check your console for errors

Comment: yes Swati. getList  in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this solution:

```
var data={       }
data[getKey(i)]= somevalue;


 var getKey = function(i) {
        return 'getList['+i+'].abcdKey';
    };
```